# User validation in adminhtml

Tags: adminhtml, extensions, payment-methods

I'm creating a Payment Method and I need to include user validation when the store configures the extension (much like a login). I've been reading a lot about it, but I can't manage to make it work.

I've tried setting an observer that fires when the user clicks on "Save Config", but I'm still figuring out how to make the observer work.

But this made me wonder: is this the best way to do what I want or is there any better way?

Comment: you need to perform some server side validation ?

Comment: Yes. I need to call a SOAP Webservice and compare the user input with the results of the SOAP call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform server side validation for the system configuration fields.

You have specify the `backend_model` to your field

> **Backend Model** – a class which allows to operate with configuration data on the different stages (save, load).
>
> It contains three major methods respectively for each event:
>   `_afterLoad()`, `_beforeSave()` and `_afterSave()`.

So in your case you can use `_beforeSave` Event

Eg :

```
<addresses>
    <label>Blocked Email Addresses</label>
    <backend_model>yourmodule/system_config_backend_yourfile</backend_model>
    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</addresses>
```

Backend Model Class :

```
<?php

class Namespace_YourModule_Model_System_Config_Backend_Yourfile extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{
    protected function _beforeSave()
    {
        if (is_array($this->getValue())) {
            /* You can perform your logic here */
        }
    }
}
```

I have Refer this [**Link**](http://www.atwix.com/magento/frontend-backend-source/)

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response!! ^_^

In which of my fields should I put the `backend_model` property: user, password or both?

Comment: you can use backend_model for password. So you can get the username value  by `Mage::getStoreConfig` and get the password value, then do the  SOAP Call.

Comment: I'm trying your idea, but when I get the username using `Mage::getStoreConfig` it's not updated, I get the value it had before saving.

I've tried using the `_afterSave` and `afterCommitCallback` events, but it's the same.

Comment: Found it! Instead of `Mage::getStoreConfig` I used  `$this->getFieldsetDataValue();` in the `_afterSave` event and it went perfectly.  Thanks a lot, @MeenakshiSundaramR !!